# Consulta aleatória do Firebase cloud firestore com ID de usuário específico (Flutter)

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, dart, random

Estou tentando puxar de forma aleatória os meus dados do cloud firestore mas não estou conseguindo, alguém sabe como fazer isso usando o ID?

```
getQustoes(String simuladoId) async{
  return await FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection("Simulado")
      .doc(simuladoId)
      .collection("QNA")
      .orderBy("id")
      .get();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

achei algo a respeito mas é bem complexo:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46798981/firestore-how-to-get-random-documents-in-a-collection

ou tente recuperar a coleção toda e randomizar no cliente. (isso não é viável se a coleção for muito grande).